# Perdida de variable en Android Studio

Tags: android, json, variables-globales

Buenas, estoy tratando de usar una consulta a una base de datos, y la verdad es que tengo varias interrogantes, primero que nada soy muy muy novato en esto, asi que puedo entender parte del código, así que ténganme paciencia.

Hago una consulta y se recuperan los datos desde el servidor, desde ahi todo funciona bien, el problema radica en que no puedo hacer uso de las variables que almaceno a lo largo de la actividad, me gustaria saber de que manera puedo lograr mantener los datos por lo menos hasta que el usuario cierre la aplicación

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.i("Login Response", response);                                                        
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        // Response from the server is in the form if a JSON, so we need a JSON Object
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success")) {
                Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                // Passing all received data from server to next activity                                     
                loginSuccess.putExtra("nombre", jsonObject.getString("nombre"));

                //loginSuccess.putExtra("cedula", jsonObject.getString("cedula"));

                loginSuccess.putExtra("correo", jsonObject.getString("correo"));

                //loginSuccess.putExtra("saldoact", jsonObject.getString("saldoact"));

                //loginSuccess.putExtra("url", jsonObject.getString("pic"));
                String correo = getIntent().getStringExtra("correo");
                String nombre = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre");
                startActivity(loginSuccess);
                finish();
            }
     ...
}
```

La aplicación funciona muy bien a decir verdad, el asunto es que cuando entro a la actividad principal y paso a otra actividad, al regresar a la actividad los datos que estaba usando se pierden, que puedo hacer para que eso no suceda.

La otra duda es que cuando hago la consulta realiza la consulta, pero cuando se sale del bucle se pierde la variable:

```
RequestSaldo RequestSaldo = new RequestSaldo(username, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("Saldo Response", response);
                //progressDialog.dismiss();

                // Response from the server is in the form if a JSON, so we need a JSON Object
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success")) {
                        xcusrsaldo = jsonObject.getString("saldoact");
                        //Toast.makeText(PagoCorreo.this, usrsaldo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(PagoCorreo.this, "Bad Response From Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }



        });requestQueue.add(RequestSaldo);
        Toast.makeText(PagoCorreo.this, xcusrsaldo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        misaldo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saldoact);
        misaldo.setText(xcusrsaldo);
```

En ambos casos la duda es como puedo mantener la variable que estoy consultando en el JSON.

Edito:
Mi main activity esta configurado para que lea Login.class, no se si eso puede ser un error, Cuando paso al main activity puedo mostrar los datos, pero al momento de retornar no, lo otro es que no se como declarar una variable de forma global, pues me gustaria y creo que esa seria una solucion declarar una variable globalmente que pueda ser accedida por todas las actividades, en ultima instancia si no logro he pensado quizas en usar base de datos sqlite. EL problema es que si uso la base de datos debo eliminar los datos una vez salga del sistema para no sobrecargar de data la aplicacion.

Aqui esta mi Login class:

```
@Override
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //conexion a la base de datos
    EditText txtusername, txtpassword;
    Button bt_login;
    TextView tv_register;
    String username, password;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        setTitle("Bienvenido a E-pay"); //set title of the activity
        txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
        txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        bt_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
        tv_register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_register);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);//Creating the RequestQueue

        //proceso al hacer click al boton de entrar
        bt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                username = txtusername.getText().toString();
                password = txtpassword.getText().toString();


                if (validateUsername(username) && validatePassword(password)) { //Username and Password Validation
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);

                    progressDialog.setTitle("Por favor aguarda un momento");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Ingresando al sistema");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.show();

                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.i("Login Response", response);
                            //progressDialog.dismiss();

                            // Response from the server is in the form if a JSON, so we need a JSON Object
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success")) {
                                    Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    //Passing all received data from server to next activity
                                    loginSuccess.putExtra("nombre", jsonObject.getString("nombre"));
                                    //loginSuccess.putExtra("cedula", jsonObject.getString("cedula"));
                                    loginSuccess.putExtra("correo", jsonObject.getString("correo"));
                                    //loginSuccess.putExtra("saldoact", jsonObject.getString("saldoact"));
                                    //loginSuccess.putExtra("url", jsonObject.getString("pic"));
                                    startActivity(loginSuccess);
                                    finish();
                                } else {

                                    if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("NOEXISTE")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Tu correo no esta registrado, si no tienes cuenta, create una", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                    if
                                            (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("PASSWORD")){
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Hay un error en tu contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("NOVERIFICADO")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Tu correo no ha sido verificado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Intent mostrarmensaje = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivarCorreo.class);
                                        startActivity(mostrarmensaje);

                                    }



                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Bad Response From Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }



                    });requestQueue.add(loginRequest);



                }
            }
        });





        // enlace si no tienes cuenta
        tv_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    private boolean validateUsername(String string) {
        if (string.equals("")) {
            txtusername.setError("Ingresa tu correo");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() > 120) {
            txtusername.setError("Máximo 120 Cáracteres");
            return false;
        }
        txtusername.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
    private boolean validatePassword(String string) {
        if (string.equals("")) {
            txtpassword.setError("Ingresa tu clave");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() > 32) {
            txtpassword.setError("Maximo 32 Cáracteres");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() < 8) {
            txtpassword.setError("Minimo 8 Cáracteres");
            return false;
        }
        txtpassword.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, he resuelto el problema para poder usar la variable de forma temporal durante la ejecucion de mi aplicación.

He creado un archivo llamado Constantes.java

El código es el siguiente:

`class Constantes {
    public static String NOMBRE = "";
    public static String CORREO = "";
    public static String SALDO = "";
 }`

Después de la consulta json a mi base de datos, almaceno los valores en esas constantes, las cuales estan disponibles en cualquier parte de mi aplicacion:

`Constantes.NOMBRE=jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                                    Constantes.CORREO=jsonObject.getString("correo");
                                    Constantes.SALDO=jsonObject.getString("saldoact");`

y para llamarlos en cualquier actividad (usuada mayormente con cajas de texto, lo que hago es un settext(constantes.CORREO)

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a tu primera pregunta esto sucede debido a que la actividad una vez que se muestra en pantalla se destruye antes de volver a reanudarse, por lo que se pierden todos lo datos que tengas en pantalla. Otro caso en que te puede pasar lo mismo es cuando rotas la pantalla.

Para ello lo que necesitas es almacenar todos los datos antes en el método **onSaveInstanceState()** y luego los recuperas en **onRestoreInstanceState()**, asignando los valores que deseas que persistan en el bundle. Estos pueden ser Obejetos, String, Enteros, etc.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("obj", myClass);  // Si se trata de un objeto
        outState.putString("llaveString", myString)  // Si es String
        outState.putInt("llaveEntero", myEntero)  // Si es un entero
    }

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    uper.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myClass = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("obj"));
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("llaveString"));
    Integer myEntero = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("llaveEntero"));
}
```

En android lo que debes dominar es el control del ciclo de vida de las actividades y fragmentos para evitar porblemas con este, con todo te dejo este [enlace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState) donde encontrarás a mas detalle como funciona cada método.

Espero mi respuesta te haya ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Buenas, interesante tu respuesta, la voy a leer, disculpame, como puedo integrar ese codigo que me has dado al codigo que ya tengo implementado?

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es crear una variable la cual sea visible para todos los métodos de la actividad, luego, en el metodo onSaveInstanceState() cargas el bundle, y en onRestoreInstanceState() cargas la variable para así llenar las vistas que estas usando. Si gustas abre un chat para ayudarte, ya que noto que la actividad en la cual debes hacer esto es en MainActivity y esta actividad no has proporcionado el código, para saber que vistas realmente cargas. Saludos.

Comment: Donde abro el chat?